# Setting multiple First name in SFMC mobile connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio, mobileconnect, content-builder

I tried to create multiple from name in mobile connect for a single Business Unit. But I can create only one in a bu. Do we have any other options to create multiple from name in a bu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only create one account level from name in each BU. However ampscript does work within this field.

And each message can have a configured from name

Check out the help doc: [From Names](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_moc_setting_the_from_name_for_your_mobileconnect_account.htm&type=5)

> After it’s configured, all outbound messages sent from your account use the From Name. Outbound messages include both triggered sends and keyword responses. You can also set From Names at the level of a long code or a message. Code- or message-level from names override account-level from names. You can also set different from names for the business units within an Enterprise 2.0 account.

Comment: Thank you @EazyE.Thats great

Comment: if the answer solved your issue you should mark it